# Creating multiple NSTimers for future update

Tags: ios, nstimer

I want my user to be able to tap a button and set a timer for a future date. If they tap the button multiple times I want to set multiple future events. What I have so far is this:

```
- (IBAction)setFutureButtonTapped:(id)sender {
     NSTimer *futureTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(futureMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

This causes futureMethod to be called once in 30 seconds, however, if I press the button once, then again in 10 seconds, I would like future method to be called at time 30, and time 40. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is that not working? Looks fine to me

Comment: No Im only gettting the first timer

Comment: There is no problem in this code. I even tested it!

Comment: Ya I thought that too but Im only getting one method call...

Comment: Is this all of the code?

Comment: ya. This is on a background thread though cause I don't want to clog the UI. I think that's what's causing it...